# BASIC GUESSING GAME

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi all I hope you can explain what I am doing wrong. I am completely new to python and experimenting with basic code but it don't seem to work as i thought it might.

the program should be a simple one of guessing the right number contained in the variable, but even when guess correct it says "Nope, that's not right".

```
magic_number = 10

input("I am thinking of a number between 1 and 10, can you guess it? ")

if input == magic_number:

    print("WOW! You must be psychic, that is spot on")
else:

    print("Nope, that's not it")
```

Comment: input gives a string. Convert string to int using int(input) and compare

Comment: This would be a better question if you'd tried to isolate the immediate problem. It doesn't need to be about a "guessing game" -- it just needs to be about "why doesn't my number from `input()` match my hardcoded one?".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all you should creat a variable that will store the answer, so for example.

```
answer = input("I am thinking of a number between 1 and 10, can you guess it? ")
```

thus you will also have to change `if input == magic_number:` to `if answer == magic_number:`

Nonetheless, the main problem is that when you enter something using the `input` method your input is automatically converted to a string. 
So you have two choices:

1. Convert your magic number to a string (`magic_number = 10`to `magic_number = "10"`) and run the code with the modifications that I have proposed
2. Convert your input too and Int modifying `if answer == magic_number:` to `if int(answer) == magic_number:`

Both of the methods work great, though be careful with the second one because if you input something that is not convertible to an int (for example "Hello", the code will return an error)

Answer (score 0):

input isn't a variable, it's a function! You should type x=input("Enter a number"), and if x == magic_number. input returns a value, but you aren't storing the user's input anywhere.

Answer (score -1):

try this :

```
    magic_number = 10
guess = int(input("I am thinking of a number between 1 and 10, can you guess it? "))
if guess == magic_number:
    print("WOW! You must be psychic, that is spot on")
else:
    print("Nope, that's not it")
```

Comment: this won't work ass guess will guess is a string and magic_number is an integer